# Selenium webdriver Python | TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to get the Phone name ,description, price from the grid.

However getting the below error:

element = id.find_elements(By.XPATH("//div[contains(@class,'ProductModule__imageAndDescriptionWrapper')]"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.tatacliq.com/apple/c-mbh12e00008")

id = driver.find_element_by_id('grid-container')

element = id.find_elements(By.XPATH("//div[contains(@class,'ProductModule__imageAndDescriptionWrapper')]"))

print(element)

for i in element:
    print(i.get_attribute('a'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'a' isn't attribute but a tag. So you have to call `href` as attribute

```
element = id.find_elements(By.XPATH("//div[contains(@class,'ProductModule__imageAndDescriptionWrapper')]"))

print(element)

for i in element:
    print(i.a.get_attribute('href'))


#OR



element = id.find_elements(By.XPATH("//div[contains(@class,'ProductModule__imageAndDescriptionWrapper')]/a"))

print(element)

for i in element:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: yes got it thanks. just a one change in syntax suggested by  @sudden_appearance

Comment: However this code is not working in --headless mode, do you have any idea why ?

Comment: To evade detection you have to use open  mode , otherwise headless mode is showing bot detection as a result getting error

Comment: open as in which mode ?

Comment: open mode  means default, you don't do nothing meaning if you don't use  -- headless  then  it's called open mode. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be

```
element = id.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'ProductModule__imageAndDescriptionWrapper')]")
```